# Where's the netlogon folder stored?

Tags: netlogon

Where will I find the netlogon diretory on a Window 2003 domain controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

C:\WINDOWS\SYSVOL\domain\scripts

Answer (score 18):

`C:\WINDOWS\sysvol\sysvol\*yourdomain*\scripts`

the scripts folder is shared with the name NETLOGON

- this is by default installation
- *yourdomain* is the name of your domain

Comment: Same files seem to be in 2 places

Comment: @Simon: They're not. Do a "DIR" in your C:\WINDOWS\SYSVOL\SYSVOL directory and you'll see "<JUNCTION>" specified on the directly listed there. It's an NTFS junction point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968829(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you have DFS it is `C:\Windows\SYSVOL_DFSR\domain\scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

[To quote a frequent phrase](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/default.aspx) from a famous Microsoft blog ... don't be helpless. On a domain controller, type the following in a command line:

```
NET SHARE
```

It will show you.